# How to get a string from ToolStripDropDownButton item clicked?

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstripdropdown

btn1 is ToolStripDropDownButton

How can I say this

```
private void btn1_DropDownItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{
 MessageBox.Show(btn1.CurrentItem.Text.ToString()); // CurrentItem = item clicked.
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
private void btn1_DropDownItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{
  MessageBox.Show(e.ClickedItem.Text); // ClickedItem = item clicked.
}
```